# Create relationships in hashtags

Tags: laravel, relationship, hashcode

I want to create a hashtags system. Currently I have this code:

```php
private function hashtags($post){
  $htag = '#';
  $arr = explode(" ", $post->description);
  $arrc = count($arr);
  $i = 0;
  while($i < $arrc){
    if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) === $htag ){
      $hash = Hashtag::where('name', ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))
                     ->where('slug', str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#')))
                     ->first();
      if(!$hash){
        Hashtag::create([
          'name' => ltrim($arr[$i], '#'),
          'type' => 1,
          'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))
        ]);
      }

      $current_hash = Hashtag::where('type', 1)
                             ->where('name', ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))
                             ->first();
      \DB::insert('insert into hashtag_post (hashtag_id, post_id) values (' .$current_hash->id. ', ' .$post->id. ')');
    }
    $i++;
  }

}
```

This code isn't good for me because I prefer use attach method but if I try use `$post->hashtags()->attach([1, 2, 3]);` or other array which I created with hashtag's id, it display error:

> "Call to undefined method App\Post::hashtags()".

My question is:How I can use attach with this example and how I can improve my code. It doesn't look well.

Comment: Please can you show the code you had for you `hashtags()` belongsToMany  relationship.

Comment: What class is the `private function hashtags` from (the one that's at the top of your question)?

Comment: I call this function in other method (which store posts). This method store new tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your relationships should be `public` methods.

Secondly, both relationships should be `belongsToMany`.

**Post** class

```php
public function hashtags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hashtag::class);
}
```

**Hashtag** class

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

---

Just an FYI, Laravel comes with helper methods that can reduce how much you have to write e.g. [firstOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods). So, this:

```
$hash = Hashtag::where('name', ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))
                     ->where('slug', str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#')))
                     ->first();
if(!$hash){
    Hashtag::create([
      'name' => ltrim($arr[$i], '#'),
      'type' => 1,
      'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))
    ]);
}
```

can become:

```
$hash = Hash::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => ltrim($arr[$i], '#'), 'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))],
    ['type' => 1]
);
```

Comment: It doesn't works. I had on hasMany and one belongsToMany but I change it
Currently, I have this code:
`protected function hashtags(){
      return $this->berlongsToMany(Hashtag::class);
    }`
`protected function posts(){
 
      return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }`
I don't know how insert the code in comment :(

Comment: @polishboy14f4 Your relationships should be `public` methods (not `protected` or `private`).